# Issue detecting textures in Unity C#

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine, textures

I am trying to program a Unity Minesweeper game, and I am almost done, but as part of it I have a boolean variable called "isCovered" that works out if the square has been clicked or not. 
This variable is used to see if the player has won yet. I have a 2d array that stores all of my squares, and to see if you win yet, it checks the array for covered, non mine squares, and if it finds them, concludes that you have not won yet.
However, when I test it, the code does not seem to find any squares that are covered, even though I can see that there are some. I concluded this because it outputs the "you win" message every time I click a safe square, even when I am not finished.
My variable is declared using this code:

```
public class Square : MonoBehaviour {
    //creates boolean variable
    public bool IsCovered() {
        //checks if the square still uses the default texture.
        return GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.texture.name == "Default";
    }
}
```

and the code to determine if you win, which is within a different class (that is my array/grid) is:

```
public static bool gameWon()
{
    // Checks all squares in the array
    foreach (Square elem in elements)
        // Tries to find a covered, safe square
        if (elem.IsCovered() && !elem.dangerous)
            // The player is not finished
            return false;
    // The player has won
    return true;
}
```

The asset that is used for the default texture is called "Uncleared proposed", rather than "Default" so I don't know if that is an issue.

My entire "Square" code for each individual tile is:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Square : MonoBehaviour
{
    //is this dangerous?
    public bool dangerous;

    //creates boolean variable
    public bool IsCovered()
    {
        //checks if the square still uses the default texture.
        return GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.texture.name == "Default";
    }
    //different textures
    public Sprite[] emptyTextures;
    public Sprite dangerTexture;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        //game randomly decides if square is dangerous
        //10% chance for initial testing
        //Chance likely to be changed at some point
        dangerous = Random.value < 0.1;

        //registers square in grid
        int x = (int)transform.position.x;
        int y = (int)transform.position.y;
        Grid.elements[x, y] = this;
    }

    void OnMouseUpAsButton()
    {
        // It's dangerous
        if (dangerous)
        {
            //uncover all mines
            //calls for procedure "uncoverDanger()" from class "Grid"
            Grid.uncoverDanger();
            //ToDo: display loss screen
            // game over
            print("Game Over");
        }
        // It's not a mine
        else
        {
            // change to correct texture
            int x = (int)transform.position.x;
            int y = (int)transform.position.y;
            loadTexture(Grid.adjacentCount(x, y));

            //Flood Fill nearby area
            Grid.FFuncover(x, y, new bool[Grid.w, Grid.h]);

            // checks if the player has won
            if (Grid.gameWon() == true)
                //tells the player they have won
                print("you win");
        }
    }

    //Loads a different texture
    public void loadTexture(int adjacentCount)
    {
        //checks to see if square is dangerous
        if (dangerous)
            //Changes to correct texture using Unity Component
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = dangerTexture;
        //if not dangerous
        else
            //changes to correct texture using Unity Component
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = emptyTextures[adjacentCount];
    }
}
```

and my Grid class code is:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grid {

    public static int w = 10; // w is the width of the grid (10)
    public static int h = 13; // h is the height of the grid (13)
    public static Square[,] elements = new Square[w, h];

    //Uncover all mines when losing
    public static void uncoverDanger() {
        foreach (Square elem in elements)
            if (elem.dangerous)
                elem.loadTexture(0);
    }

    // Determines if the square is dangerous
    public static bool dangerAt(int x, int y)
    {
        // Makes sure the square is in the range
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < w && y < h)
            // Checks if the square is dangerous
            return elements[x, y].dangerous;
        return false;
    }

    // Counts number of dangerous squares adjacent
    public static int adjacentCount(int x, int y)
    {
        int count = 0;
        //checks adjacent squares
        //potentially adds to counter
        if (dangerAt(x, y + 1)) ++count; // top
        if (dangerAt(x + 1, y + 1)) ++count; // top-right
        if (dangerAt(x + 1, y)) ++count; // right
        if (dangerAt(x + 1, y - 1)) ++count; // bottom-right
        if (dangerAt(x, y - 1)) ++count; // bottom
        if (dangerAt(x - 1, y - 1)) ++count; // bottom-left
        if (dangerAt(x - 1, y)) ++count; // left
        if (dangerAt(x - 1, y + 1)) ++count; // top-left
        //outputs value
        return count;
    }

    // Flood Fill (FF) safe squares
    public static void FFuncover(int x, int y, bool[,] visited)
    {
        // Checks if coordinates in range
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < w && y < h)
        {
            // Filled already?
            if (visited[x, y])
                return;

            //uncovers a square
            elements[x, y].loadTexture(adjacentCount(x, y));

            //checks if adjacencyCount is not 0
            if (adjacentCount(x, y) > 0)
                //ends algorithm
                return;

            // set square as visited
            visited[x, y] = true;
            // repeates with all 4 adjacent squares (not using diagonal)
            FFuncover(x - 1, y, visited);
            FFuncover(x + 1, y, visited);
            FFuncover(x, y - 1, visited);
            FFuncover(x, y + 1, visited);
        }
    }

    public static bool gameWon()
    {
        // Checks all squares in the array
        foreach (Square elem in elements)
            // Tries to find a covered, safe square
            if (elem.IsCovered() && !elem.dangerous)
                // The player is not finished
                return false;
        // The player has won
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am a real newbie to unity so it might be something stupid, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Name property of the texture2d class that return the name of the object rather than the texture name.Maybe you should change IsCovered() I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I am an idiot, I just had to change the name of the texture in the variable code to "Uncleared proposed", I don't know why it didn't work earlier.